# Should I be 301 redirecting query strings in shopping carts?

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, shopping-cart, query-string, url-parameters

Should I redirect query strings in a shopping cart discovered by Google Webmaster Tools, which we don't want to show up there.

Should we 301 URL like this?

> **example.com**=**shop.ask**&product_id=31&subject=Call+for+Pricing%3Aproductname%3B%80%93&option=com_**virtuemart**&Itemid=146

What I thought was, what if this URL indicates a customer's purchase? I mean he selected a product, came to the checkout page and suddenly he's 301 back to product page where he started?

Could this happen?

What do you advise me to do?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to redirect them - that will probably break your site's functionality. There are various means of managing parameters for SEO purposes; since you mention Google Webmaster Tools, you may wish to look at their [parameter management tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1235687?hl=en).

In brief, you can instruct Google how to handle different parameters on your site, e.g., index them, index a representative URL, etc. Bing has a similar tool.